# What does being an "elementary substance" mean?

Tags: elements

> Which of the following isn't an elementary substance?
>
> 1. Ozone
> 2. Sulfur
> 3. diamond
> 4. quartz

I don't get what **elementary substance** means.

By seeing the options and the word elementary, I guess it means something like pure or obtained in its original form.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [LATINTOS](http://golatintos.blogspot.com/2013/03/a-term-in-chemistry-elementary-substance.html):

> An elementary substance is a pure chemical substance that consists of atoms belonging to a single chemical element.

Now you should be able to solve your question.

Comment: ok so it's quartz.